# Why vue acts differently with Laravel than standalone vue app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I don't know why Vue acts differently with Laravel than standalone Vue app. Maybe I can't understand the environment it needs to work correctly. Here is what's happening which made me post this question.

When I install standalone Vue app, Let's say, when I install it in a completely different directory using `vue init webpack vueapp`, It works as it should. When I update anything in `.vue` file, It gets updated in the browser too which is expected behaviour in my mind or maybe it's because I am executing it in a development environment using `npm run dev`.

But when I use vue with laravel, I can load the modules and I can see loaded modules in the browser, but when I update something a component, It won't update in the browser! It just does not. I have to reload a page every time I update markup in the component file.

Also, when I execute `npm run dev` in the vue app with Laravel, It does not take over the terminal as it does in the standalone vue app. It is obvious as we can't execute vue as well as laravel in the same development environment as vue uses nodejs which uses the port 8080 and apache uses the port 80.

I don't know what I am missing but it's eating my head since last few days. I surfed almost all the tutorials available on the internet and all the available StackOverflow questions but still, I can't get it! I think it's the normal behaviour but I have less experience with vue.js as I am a newbie in vue.js.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `npm run hot` for hot module reloading. `npm run watch` will detect file changes, but some systems it doesn't work so there is `npm run watch --poll` to periodically poll for file changes. The big difference between a Laravel installation and a project created using the vue cli is Laravel Mix. It abstracts a lot of the webpack configuration.

Comment: Don't use browsersync. This just reloads the page. You're looking for hot module replacement, which is `npm run hot`. You may need to swap out any included internal JS or CSS file references for the mix(...) reference found in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is true and it was meant to be that way.

But you can use a library that comes with`laravel` to accomplish that. first.

add `.browserSync();` to your `webpack.mix.js`

instead of `npm run dev` use `npm run watch`. This will help you not to refresh.

and that is how you have the same effect. Hope its not much.

Comment: I can execute `npm run watch` with laravel. Till now, It was not updating stuff as expected. I am trying with `.browserSync();` now. Hope it will start working as expected.

Comment: instead of php artisan serve , use php artisan serve --host php artisan serve --host=0

Comment: I am not using `php artisan serve`. I have defined host in `/etc/hosts` and has created virtualhost to point the host to document root.

Comment: `browserSync` does not seem to work even with `npm run watch`. I found out that `browserSync` is now removed from official documentation and we can include as  `mix('js/app.js')` and I tried it. Still not luck! haha.

Comment: i used this link to configure mine last week https://andremadarang.com/livereload-and-browsersync-with-laravel/

Comment: @p01ymath https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix#browsersync-reloading is still in the official documentation of laravel at least